# WebClient powershell Download return an empty file

Tags: image, file, powershell, download, webclient

I am trying to download the image below into a local directory but the resulted image appears empty.

http://www.capecountyhomes.com/Homes/Images/Listings/77977723/1/Photo.jpg

This seems like a simple task but for some reason, the resulted image is somehow 0 bytes. below is my code

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$wc.DownloadFile("http://www.capecountyhomes.com/Homes/Images/Listings/77977723/1/Photo.jpg","C:/images/test.jpeg")
```

but the image test.jpeg in my local directory is 0 bytes.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo, but your calling the `DownloadFile` method on a non-existing object.

Comment: @Graimer, that was a typo. it is corrected now. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work. What I can contribute with however is a confirmation that `Invoke-WebRequest` (PS3.0 cmdlet) does work. If I save all the data in the `Content` property retrieved with `Invoke-WebRequest`, I get the picture. `WebRequest` and `WebClient` however doesn't work, even though it returns a 200 OK status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have something to do with the Headers, if you add a User-Agent the download seems to work:

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Safari"
$wc.DownloadFile("http://www.capecountyhomes.com/Homes/Images/Listings/77977723/1/Photo.jpg","C:/images/test.jpeg")
```

Probably blank user agents are denied access as a measure against spam.

Comment: This was my idea too. It's weird that `Invoke-WebRequest` works though, since Technet says it's default UserAgent is "none"/blank. But if this works, it works. Nothing to complain about = )

Comment: The user-agent for Invoke-WebRequest is (on my computer): User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.2; nl-BE) WindowsPowerShell/3.0

Answer (score 0):

The url does not exist so I can't test, but my guess is the file really is 0 bytes in size.

Comment: The url exists. I can access it just fine. see below http://www.capecountyhomes.com/Homes/Images/Listings/77977723/1/Photo.jpg

Comment: Sorry, www.capecountyhomes.com is not reachable for me at all